# Linear transformation notation: $[f]_{B_i}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem states: let $B_1$ $B_2$ and $B_3$be 3 bases of $\mathbb C^3$ over $\mathbb C$

\begin{align}
B_1&=\{(1,0,0);(1,1,0);(1,1,1)\}\\
B_2&=\{(1,1,0);(1,0,0);(1,1,1)\}\\
B_3&=\{(2,0,i);(1,0,0);(0,2i,0)\}
\end{align}

And let $f(x,y,z)=(2x+3iy,0,3x-iz)$

Find $[f]_{B_1}, [f]_{B_2}, [f]_{B_3}$

What does $[f]_{B_i}$ mean? I'm guessing it has something to do with the order of the base because of $B_1$and$B_2$ having the same elements in different order but then again maybe not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Joe Johnson 126, $[f]_{B_i}$ denotes the matrix representation of $f$ w.r.t. $B_i$, $i=1,2,3$.

This is done by calculating the images of the basis vectors, $f(b_1^i),f(b_2^i), f(b_3^i)$, and finding their coordinates w.r.t. $B_i$. These coordinate vectors are the columns of the matrix $[f]_{B_i}$ (in that order).

One of your questions was: What's the difference between $[f]_{B_1}$ and $[f]_{B_2}$?

Firstly, $f(1,0,0)$ will have different coordinates w.r.t. $B_1$ and $B_2$, in particular the first and second row will be switched. The same will happen with $f(1,1,0)$.

Furthermore, $[f]_{B_1}$ will have the coordinates of $f(1,0,0)$ as the first column, and 
the coordinates of $f(1,1,0)$ as the second column, whereas $[f]_{B_2}$ will have these interchanged. So, to sum up, you will see the same numbers in the matrices $[f]_{B_1}$ and $[f]_{B_2}$, but they will have switched places.

Comment: Ok so for $B_1=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ I need to find the matrix A so that $A (input wrt B_1) = (output wrt B_1)$ right? A given vector $(x,y,z)$ in the canonic form would be written $(x-y,y-z,z)$ wrt $B_1$ right? Then I to find the corresponding output values first I apply $f$ to the basis vectors in canonic form (because that's how it was defined, right?): $f(1,0,0)=2b_1-3b_2+3b_3,\ f(1,1,0)=(2+3i)b_1-3b_2+3b_3,\ f(1,1,1)=(2+3i)b_1-(3-i)b_2+(3-i)b_3$

Comment: Finally I look for the $3x3$ matrix that gives me

 $A \begin{pmatrix}
        1  \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ =
$\begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\
        -3 \\
        3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ $\qquad$  $A \begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        1  \\
        0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ =
$\begin{pmatrix}
        2+3i \\
        -3 \\
        3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ $\qquad$  $A \begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        0  \\
        1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ =
$\begin{pmatrix}
        2+3i \\
        -3+i \\
        3-i \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: so  $A  =
$\begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 2+3i & 2+3i\\
        -3 & -3 & -3+i\\
        3 & 3 & 3-i\\
        \end{pmatrix}

is this OK or completely wrong?

Comment: Assuming that you have found the right coordinates for $f(1,0,0)$ and so on, this is the right approach. Do the columns of $A$ resemble something?

Comment: yes, the output vectors wrt $B_1$! So a faster approach would be just getting those output vectors and just writing them as columns of the matrix I'm looking for

Comment: Yes, writing the output vectors w.r.t. $B_1$ finds the columns of the representing matrix w.r.t. $B_1$. My answer contained a different phrasing of this observation. :)

Comment: Awesome thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

It is asking you to find the matrix representation of $f$ with repsect to the basis $B_i$.

Comment: And I suspect that notation was given in that book previously.  (If not, it is a very bad book.)